# Linux is not appearing on boot menu

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, boot-manager

After updating BIOS I am able to run Windows only, but not Linux:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBVw.jpg)

However, after plugging in pendrive with linux subsystem, using "Boot Rescue" option, I am able to see all .efi files and run Linux properly. The Linux's .efi file is on the same partition as Windows'.

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved, unfortunately, only by the reinstalation of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the BIOS update did not change boot mode to UEFI mode only and not UEFI and legacy. You can also try to reinstall the linux grub boot menu when you run Linux properly (assuming you had a GRUB boot menu).

Comment: Reinstallation of GRUB and changing the boot mode to Legacy only have changed nothing, unfortunately. There were two options - boot mode: "Legacy support" and boot order: "Legacy first". What else should I do?

Comment: I remember something about booting linux with a live disk, then reinstalling the boot partition using gparted while the hard drive is unmounted. Also, a friend of mine once had an issue with something called "secure boot", so you might want to check those out. Sorry, can't really help any more than that.